# How to get adf-richclient-automation-11.jar compatible with the latest selenium-java 3.x

Tags: selenium-webdriver, oracle12c, oracle-adf

I'm develping Selenium tests for Oracle ADF application.

I'm using for that:

1. JDeveloper fmw_12.2.1.3.0_bpmqs installation
2. Very usefull [library SelniumTools](https://github.com/adfemg/adf-selenium)

And I faced with problem:

[The SelniumTools](https://github.com/adfemg/adf-selenium) based on *adf-richclient-automation-11.jar* which is distributed with JDeveloper (use can find it in *Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.view* folder) and described in docs as Oracle Customized Selenium.

And everything works fine with *selenium-java library* up to *2.53.1* version.

But when I upgrade *selenium-java library* to *3.3.1* version my test project fall with exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.**WebDriverWait.until(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;** Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800' System info: host: 'EE-LATITUDE-749', ip: '10.10.207.64', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_172' Driver info: driver.version: unknown
  com.redheap.selenium.junit.PageProvider.createPage(PageProvider.java:49)
  com.redheap.selenium.junit.PageProvider.goHome(PageProvider.java:36)
  ru.russvet.selenium.tests.P6_ProcessPageTest.(P6_ProcessPageTest.java:38)
  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.until(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;
  oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.selenium.RichWebDrivers.waitForServer(RichWebDrivers.java:112)
  oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.selenium.RichWebDrivers.waitForRichPageToLoad(RichWebDrivers.java:175)
  oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.selenium.RichWebDrivers.waitForRichPageToLoad(RichWebDrivers.java:158)
  com.redheap.selenium.page.Page.(Page.java:53)
  com.redheap.selenium.page.Page.(Page.java:45)
  ru.russvet.selenium.pages.BPMWorkspaceLoginPage.(BPMWorkspaceLoginPage.java:19)
  com.redheap.selenium.junit.PageProvider.createPage(PageProvider.java:47)
```

Investigations follow to the reason:

1) in *selenium-java library* starting from *3.3.1* interface for *until* function has been changed and accept *Function, Predicate или Supplier* classes from *Java 8 library* instead of *Guava library* https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/b2aa9fd534f7afbcba319231bb4bce85f825ef09 :

```
-import com.google.common.base.Function;   
-import com.google.common.base.Predicate;   
-import com.google.common.base.Supplier;  
+import java.util.function.Function;  
+import java.util.function.Predicate;  
+import java.util.function.Supplier;
```

2) what could be probably worked around with recent guava release (21+ version), where the Google versions of both Function and Predicate extend the Java 8 equivalents

So, it is look like that *adf-richclient-automation-11.jar* is built with *selenium-java library 2.x*, and that causes the exception during running the tests.

We raised it via Oracle support, but there is no information from them about new version for this library yet.

So, my questions are:
1) what is possible way to rebuild the *adf-richclient-automation-11.jar* to make it compatible with the latest version of selenium-java as 3.x?

2) Has anybody found newer version of *adf-richclient-automation-11.jar* in maybe some specific distribution of JDeveloper?

Answer (score 0):

I was once upon a time part of the small team within Oracle that built the automation library you are referring to.

The issue here is API compatibility and unless the ADF automation library is repackaged against WebDriver 3.x and redistributed by Oracle OTN, you have no options but to stick to using Selenium 2.x libraries. WebDriver 3.x is meant for Java 8, which would be one more reason Oracle would want to soon upgrade to 3.x. Have you raised your concerns via OTN forums or Oracle support?

Comment: your replay confirmed my thoughts. Yes, we raise both this question via OTN forum and via our customer's Oracle support account. However, the formal process with Oracle probably will take 2-3 month... If and when we'll got official news I'll share it here. By the way, is it possible that some version of JDeveloper distribution could include the newer version of mentioned library?

Answer (score 0):

Well, answer myself. The only way for now to make this works were decompiling `adf-richclient-automation-11.jar`, clean and repackage it against WebDriver 3.x.

The corresponding Eclipse project is here https://github.com/EgorBEremeev/adf-richclient-automation-selenium-3-rebuild

This project does not contains test classes as original lib. I didn't run any tests from the original lib because I have no idea of required test environment for that.
So, I tested the repackaged library directly in my main project.

How ever the complete steps to get sources, clean it, fix errors and repackage library you can find in readme.md in the git repository and as well below:

## Full Steps to manualy rebuilt adf-richclient-automation-11.jar:

### Environment

1. Install Eclipse
2. Install Decompiler pluging

```
    Help -> Marketplace -> Enhanced Class Decompiler
    Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Decompiler -> Default Class Decompiler: CFR -> Applay and Close
```

3. Set User Libraries

```
    Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries
         New->
            Name -> selenium-java-3.3.1
            Add External JARs... ->
                path\to\selenium-java-3.3.1\
                    client-combined-3.3.1-nodeps.jar
                    lib\*.jar
         ->Finish

         New->
            Name -> adf-richclient-automation-11.jar
            Add External JARs... ->
                path\to\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.view\
                    adf-richclient-automation-11.jar
         ->Finish
     -> Applay and Close
```

### Steps

1. Create Java Project

```
Eclipse -> New -> Java Project
    Name -> project_name
    JDK -> 1.8
    Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> User Library -> Next
        User Libraries ...
            selenium-java-3.3.1
            adf-richclient-automation-11.jar
```

2. Decompile adf-richclient-automation-11.jar

```
Project Explorer -> adf-richclient-automation-11.jar -> Context Menu -> Export Sources
    path\to\project_name\src\
        adf-richclient-automation-11-src.zip
    Project Explorer -> Refresh
        src -> adf-richclient-automation-11-src.zip
```

3. Extract decompiled sources into path\to\project_name\src\
4. Check the src

```
Project Explorer -> Refresh
        src -> adf-richclient-automation-11-src.zip
                * oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.selenium
                * oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.test
                   oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.test.browserfactory
                * oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.test.component
                * oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.test.selenium
                   org.openqa.selenium
                   org.openqa.selenium.firefox
```

5.1 Delete classes used for and with Selenium RC:

```
        path/to/project_name/src/
        oracle/adf/view/rich/automation/selenium/RichSelenium.java -> Delete
```

5.2 Delete packages oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.test.* -> Delete

```java
            oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.test
            oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.test.browserfactory
            oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.test.component
            oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.test.selenium
```

6. Fix errors:

   - path/to/project_name/src/oracle/adf/view/rich/automation/selenium/RichWebDrivers.java

     - [] 241 Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String ->

   ```java
   fix 239 -> List<String> logs = (List) jsExecutor.executeScript(_GET_AND_CLEAR_LOG_MESSAGES_JS,
    = 
    List<String> logs = (List) jsExecutor.executeScript(_GET_AND_CLEAR_LOG_MESSAGES_JS,
            new Object[]{logLevel.toString().toUpperCase()});
    for (String s : logs) {
        sbf.append(s).append(_NEW_LINE);
    }
   ```

   - [] 321 Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String ->

   ```java
   fix 320 -> Set<String> handles = webDriver.getWindowHandles();
    =
    public String apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
        Set<String> handles = webDriver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String handle : handles) {
            if (openWindowHandles.contains(handle))
                continue;
            return handle;
        }
        return null;
    }
   ```
7. Build and Export into jar

```
 remove -> path\to\project_name\src\adf-richclient-automation-11-src.zip
 Project Explorer -> Export -> Java -> JAR file -> Next
     select src folder only
     check Export generated classes and resources
     uncheck .classpath, .project
         -> Finish -> Ok in warning dialog
```

8. Optional fix error in classes from oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.test.* packages.

   - path/to/project_name/src/oracle/adf/view/rich/automation/test/selenium/WebDriverManager.java

     - [] 87 Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String ->

   ```java
    fix 85 Set<String> windowHandles = webDriver.getWindowHandles();
    =
    try {
        Set<String> windowHandles = webDriver.getWindowHandles();
        _LOG.fine("try to close all windows... ");
        for (String handle : windowHandles) {
   ```

   - path/to/project_name/src/oracle/adf/view/rich/automation/test/selenium/RichWebDriverTest.java

     - [] 953 Syntax error on token "finally", delete this token ->

   ```java
   fix -> delete  956,952,949, 941
    =
    protected void refresh() {
        _LOG.fine("Executing refresh()");
        this.getWebDriver().navigate().refresh();
        try {
            Alert alert = this.getWebDriver().switchTo().alert();
            if (alert != null) {
                alert.accept();
            };
        }
        catch (WebDriverException alert) {}
        finally {
            this.waitForPage();
        }
    }
   ```

   - [] 1026 Unreachable catch block for Exception. It is already handled by the catch block for Throwable ->

   ```java
    fix -> replace whole method by variant of Jad Decompiler-> 
        -> Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Decompiler -> Default Class Decompiler: Jad -> Applay and Close
        -> fix 1020, 1028 Duplicate local variable cachingEnabled ->
            fix-> delete
                -> 1019 String msg;
                -> 1018 boolean cachingEnabled;
    =
    protected void onShutdownBrowser() {
        _LOG.finest("Shutting down browser");
        try {
            _logSeleniumBrowserLogAndResetLoggerLevel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            boolean cachingEnabled;
            String msg;
                _LOG.warning("The page did not generate any logs.");
        } finally {
            boolean cachingEnabled = isBrowserCachingEnabled();
            try {
                if (cachingEnabled) {
                    getWebDriverManager().releaseInstance();
                } else {
                    getWebDriverManager().destroyInstance();
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                String msg = cachingEnabled
                        ? "Failed to release the browser. Error message: %s"
                        : "Failed to shutdown the browser. Error message: %s";
                _LOG.severe(String.format(msg, new Object[]{t.getMessage()}));
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   - [] 1047 Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to WebElement ->

   ```java
    fix 1046 List<WebElement> allOptions = element.findElements(By.xpath((String) builder.toString()));
    =
    List<WebElement> allOptions = element.findElements(By.xpath((String) builder.toString()));
    for (WebElement option : allOptions) {
   ```

   - path/to/project_name/src/oracle/adf/view/rich/automation/test/UrlFactories.java

     - [] 34 Type mismatch: cannot convert from UrlFactory to UrlFactories.UrlFactoryImpl ->

   ```java
    fix Add cast to 'UrlFactoryImpl'
    =
    factory = (UrlFactoryImpl) urlFactoryIterator.next();
   ```

   - [] 52 Type mismatch: cannot convert from UrlFactory to UrlFactories.UrlFactoryImpl

   ```java
    fix Add cast to 'UrlFactoryImpl'
    =
    UrlFactoryImpl urlFactoryImpl = (UrlFactoryImpl) (_INSTANCE = factory != null ? factory : new UrlFactoryImpl());
   ```